# How to load Json array into a Dropdown using reactjs/jquery

Tags: jquery, json, reactjs

I am trying to load a json file data which full names(Branch names from git).
 I want to load it all into a Dropdown menu, I also want it to be clickable so that I can run another node script once I click on the name.
How can I achieve this in reactjs/jquery(either)? I am very new to coding below is all I have done so far.. please help!

```
<select id="users-dropdown" style="width:200px; display:block;"></select>

        <script>        

        function buildUserList(){
            console.log(branchData)
                   for (var i=0;i<branchData.length;i++){
               var branchesDropdown = document.getElementById('users-dropdown');
                branchesDropdown options[branchesDropdown.options.length] = new Option(branchData[i].all);
            }

        }
        var my_url = 'branches.json';
        var branchData;
        var json = (function () {
            var json = null;
            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': my_url,
                'dataType': 'json',
                'success':
                // function (data) {
                    branchData = data.all;
                    buildUserList();
                }
            });
            return json;
        })(); 
        </script>
```

Here is my json data: Branches.json

```
["master","remotes/origin/1.1","remotes/origin/13.10","remotes/origin/13.11"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you could do it with React JS

```
var Dropdown = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'Dropdown',

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            options: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {

        var component = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'branches.json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                component.setState({
                    options: data
                });
            }
        });
    },
    handleClick: function () {

        //RUN YOUR CUSTOM HANDLER

    },
    render: function () {

        var i = 0;

        var options = this.state.options.map(function (option) {
            return React.createElement(
                'option',
                { value: option, key: i++ },
                option
            );
        });

        return React.createElement(
            'select',
            { onChange: this.handleClick },
            options
        );
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Dropdown, null), document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using the below.

```
  <script>        
$.getJSON("Branches.json", function (data) {
 $.each(data, function (index, item) {
     $('#users-dropdown').append(
          $('<option></option>').val(item).html(item)
      );
 });
});
        </script>
```

Comment: The OP wanted a solution with React/jQuery. This only provides a solution in jQuery.